# Change of basis, matrix form in dirac notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

> Many two-level systems can be described by the following Hamiltonian matrix:
>
> - $\left<i|\hat {H}|i\right>$ $=\alpha, i=1,2$
> - $\left<i|\hat {H}|j\right> = \beta, i\neq j$
>
> a) Find the e eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the Hamiltonian in the basis given, being careful to normalise.
>
> b) Find the similarity transformation from the initial representation to the representation using the eigenvectors
> of the molecule. Explicitly transform the Hamiltonian to the eigenvector basis, and comment on the resulting
> form.

I have done part (a) and the eigenvectors are:
$\psi_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           -1 \\
         \end{bmatrix} $

and  $\psi_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           1 \\
         \end{bmatrix} $

but I don't understand how to do the change of representation.

By this I mean, I understand the principles of it, but I just don't really get what the vectors for the initial representation are, not sure if I'm being really obtuse here....

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis

Comment: Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part (b) just means the following:

$$ \langle \psi_i | H | \psi_j \rangle\ =\ ? \quad \ i,j = 1,2 $$

You can certainly calculate that using the eigenvalue problem $H |\psi_i\rangle =  E_i |\psi_i\rangle$ (since you said you've got the eigenvalues) and the orthogonalization condition of eigenvectors. And after this, again represent the eigenstates (in terms of vectors) in this basis.

Comment: thanks! so i can use the intial i and j vectors as \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           0 \\
     
         \end{bmatrix}   and \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           1\\
     
         \end{bmatrix}

Comment: correct, the representation of eigenstates using eigenstates as the basis is just like you wrote! You can guess the form of the Hamiltonian matrix this time, right? Btw, the second part of the Hamiltonian definition should be $\langle i | H | j \rangle$ to follow the description $i \neq j$. I can't edit it because the forum requires at least editing 6 characters.

Comment: yes, I didn't see that! I have now editing it, thanks!